# Insert images into the project without them being in the Resource folder.(AppleScript App)

Tags: xcode, applescript

Is there any way to use images in the format .png or another format, and then compile these images so that they are not within the folder Resource of this project? I've seen several programs using many of the images as icons but when you open the folder resource the only image I see is the icon of the program.

Answer (score 0):

If items such as standard system icons are used you only need their paths (since they would already be installed), otherwise the image files need to be included in the project.